# Why is my input value always set in php?

Tags: php, forms, isset

I am working on my local wampserver, where I am testing a form validation with PHP ; I can't understand why my input values are always set -- `if(isset($_POST['variable']))` --, even if I enter nothing ?

This is most annoying with select tags : if I choose nothing (and then I understand there's no "selected" attribute), the first option value will be set as my choice...

Can anyone help me here ? Thanks ;-)

Comment: Hey ? I started saying hello and it disappeared ?

Comment: could you post examples of your code, please? 

nevertheless an idea: 
can it be, you have assignments (=) somewhere instead of comparisons (==) ... like: `if ($_POST['varname'] = 1) { ... ` ?
This would set your post-var to 1.

Comment: wheres the code? Help us help you!

Answer (score 2):

### Explanation

This behaviour is correct and it is the way HTML works. To solve this you also need to check that value you are getting back is correct and not just if it is set.

### Example

You could make the first value in your select empty:

```
<select name="test">
    <option value="">Please select an option...</option>
    <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
</select>
```

Then in your PHP do:

```
if(isset($_POST['test'] && !empty($_POST['test'])) {
    // there is something in the field
} else {
    // trigger error
}
```

I should probably point out here that [`empty()` will](http://php.net/empty) see 0 as empty so if you are sending back integers then you should be checking in the following way:

```
if(isset($_POST['test'] && '' !== $_POST['test']) {
    // there is something in the field
} else {
    // trigger error
}
```

Comment: I doubt isset is necessary here (if you have already checked whole form submit)

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel I think it is very important and basic programming practice to check that something exists before attempting to access it. Who is to say that the form will always be submitted in its entirety etc.

Comment: It's me saying that. It's normal behavior. If we've got only partial data, it is undobtedly an error, so it's ok to expect an *error* message.

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel you are **wrong** forms can be amended with javascript to remove fields and your code would not handle this correctly. It is not OK to trigger a PHP notice because the entire form has not come back. You should never assume that you are getting back what you expect. The application should handle this elegantly.

Comment: The **only** elegant handling of partial form is 404. So, I'll get it automatically.

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel You have commented in this way on my answers before and I am tiring of correcting you. A partial form can be valid as JS maybe used to remove fields as intended behaviour. Using a system notice to trigger your 404 for you is nowhere near explicit enough or at all elegant. I am glad that I do not have to work with or see your code.

Answer (score 1):

If it is sent as a parameter, it will be set, even if the value is an empty string.

`isset()` tells you whether the variable has been defined, not whether it's been populated.

You do need to check `isset()` on your post variables, but you can then also check if they've got a value:

```
if(isset($_POST['variable']) && $_POST['variable']!=='') { .... }
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: `!==`, otherwise this'll fail on stuff like `0`.

Answer (score 0):

You should test if it has a value:

```
if (isset($_POST['variable']) && $_POST['variable'])
```

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: Care to explain?

Comment: Care to re-read the question? Which of his problems can be solved with isset?

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: not one of his problems can be solved with `isset`. But they *will* be solved by evaluating `$_POST['variable']`. This'll be an empty string if nothing was entered in that field, and would evaluate to false. I just added `isset($_POST['variable'])` as a precaution, in case there's no field in the form with that name.

Answer (score 0):

That's the way how HTML works, you can't help it.
The only input type which is not being sent to the server is an empty checkbox (and it's irritating people in it's turn)

Just add an empty option at the top of your select tag.

Thanks to this behavior, you don't have to check every field with isset.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to unset empty input , try `array_filter($_POST)`.

Comment: that's most unusual wish I've ever seen

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using isset(), I would suggest using empty():

```
if(!empty($_POST['variable'])) {
    // do something
}
```

It is the equivalent of:

```
if (isset($_POST['variable']) && $_POST['variable']) {
    // do something
}
```

but much easier to read, and slightly lighter.

For the select tags, you can add a disabled option at the top, and then the select variable will not be submitted unless they explicitly select something.

```
<select name="variable>
    <option disabled=disabled>Select one...</option>
    //other options here
</select>
```

Answer (score -1):

What does your form look like?  According to the isset documentation located here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php , isset only returns true when the value is set or not null.

So, if your form is setting the value it is possible that that is why you're seeing this behavior.  Under normal circumstances a value that is not set should return false on an isset check.

Comment: Thanks whoever voted this down.  Sorry I couldn't do your work for you and that you would actually have to do it yourself...